# Синхронизация времени

Tags: mysql

Вопрос по поводу синхронизации времени в mysql (чтобы у пользователей с разных стран выводилась правильная дата и время).

Пользователь выбирает, когда будет заканчиваться проект (через 2 дня, 5 дней или 7 дней). После чего информация о проекте записывается в БД, а в поле `окончание проекта` (TIMESTAMP) будет записываться  Текущее время + кол-во. дней `*24*3600`.

Когда я буду производить выборку из базы, то я высчитываю сколько времени осталось до окончания проекта (например: проект заканчивается через 2 дня 3 часа 46 минут), НО ведь это время будет вычислено относительно сервера!

Вопрос: нужно ли как-нибудь синхронизировать время для того, чтобы у пользователей из разных временных зон выводилось правильное время окончания проекта (например: проект заканчивается через 2 дня 3 часа 46 минут).

Answer (score 1):

Можно придумать много реализаций (например, даже через geo ip), но во многих проектах используют очень простой и надежный выход: просят пользователя при регистрации указать его смещение относительно UTC. Его знают все, так что проблем не возникает.

Answer (score 0):

Передать переменную со временем, которое хранится в БД в javascript! javascript считывает местное время на компьютере пользователя, в этом же javascript написать функцию вычисления и выводить в нужном месте нужное время, используя этот же javascript! [Справочник объекта Date](http://javascript.ru/Date), там же примеры и методы!

Comment: ы) кто-то коомент сделал ответом) спасибо... надеюсь будет полезным)